# Change the Size of SWIOTLB Permanently in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, tlb

I work on Linux Debian with 64bit kernel version 4.19.0 and default SWIOTLB size 64M.
For the needs of a kernel driver that I develop I would like to use more than 64M SWIOTLB.
Is there any way to change the SWIOTLB size permanently.
I keep searching but it is not clear to me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Giving `swiotlb=65536` to kernel command line (e.g. `/etc/default/grub`) gives 128MB of swiotlb. To make this permanent, we can use `update-grub` command. If the hardware has hardware IOMMU, `iommu=force intel_iommu=on` usually removes the need for swiotlb.